# wpf Validation возврат значения в модель

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В общем есть такой `TextBox` к которому добавлены `ValidationRules`
Вопрос в том как правильно вернуть в модель(привязать к модели) флаг о наличии ошибки (bool HasError)?

Vmin это float 
и сожалению есть ограничение средствами только 4 frameworka.

```
<TextBox  
      Margin="5,0,0,0" 
      MaxLength="7" 
      TextWrapping="Wrap" 
      VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
      Style="{StaticResource textBoxStyle}"
      Language="ru-RU" Height="20">
         <Binding Path="Vmin" 
          TargetNullValue=""
          ValidatesOnExceptions="True"
          NotifyOnValidationError="True"
          UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
          NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True"
          StringFormat="#0.###" 
                   Converter="{StaticResource TextToFloat}"
          >
           <Binding.ValidationRules>
             <ExceptionValidationRule/>
             <rules:DoubleValidationRule MinValue="0.000" MaxValue="9999.999"/>
         </Binding.ValidationRules>
      </Binding>
</TextBox>
```

в ресурсах описан стиль который рисует рамку и выводит Tooltip

```
<Style x:Key="textBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock Margin="0 0 5 0"
                                       Text="!"
                                       FontSize="14"
                                       FontWeight="Bold"
                                       Foreground="Red"/>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2"  >
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adornedElement"/>
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

модель не привожу так как понятно что её надо будет править возможно полностью переделывать

да и не думаю что особо поможет... (хотя мог ошибаться)

фрагмент

```
    float _Vmin;
    public float Vmin
    {
        get { return _Vmin; }
        set
        {
            _Vmin = value;
            if (!_prev_Vmin.Equals(_Vmin))
            {
                HasHasChangedArray[_Vmin_] = true;
                HasChanged = true;
            }
            else
            {
                HasHasChangedArray[_Vmin_] = false;
                HasChanged = isChangedArray();
            }
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Vmin)));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, можно использовать присоединенные свойства (attached property). Для этого напишем небольшой класс-помощник.

```
internal class TextBoxValidationHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HasError", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxValidationHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, null, CoerceHasError));

    public static bool GetHasError(DependencyObject d) => 
        (bool)d.GetValue(HasErrorProperty);

    public static void SetHasError(DependencyObject d, bool value) => 
        d.SetValue(HasErrorProperty, value);

    private static object CoerceHasError(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        bool ret = (bool)baseValue;

        if (BindingOperations.IsDataBound(d, HasErrorProperty))
        {
            if (GetHasErrorDescriptor(d) == null)
            {
                DependencyPropertyDescriptor desc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Validation.HasErrorProperty, d.GetType());
                desc.AddValueChanged(d, OnHasErrorChanged);
                SetHasErrorDescriptor(d, desc);
                ret = Validation.GetHasError(d);
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (GetHasErrorDescriptor(d) != null) 
            {
                DependencyPropertyDescriptor desc = GetHasErrorDescriptor(d);
                desc.RemoveValueChanged(d, OnHasErrorChanged);
                SetHasErrorDescriptor(d, null);
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorDescriptorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HasErrorDescriptor", typeof(DependencyPropertyDescriptor), typeof(TextBoxValidationHelper));

    private static DependencyPropertyDescriptor GetHasErrorDescriptor(DependencyObject d) => 
        d.GetValue(HasErrorDescriptorProperty) as DependencyPropertyDescriptor;

    private static void SetHasErrorDescriptor(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyDescriptor value) => 
        d.SetValue(HasErrorDescriptorProperty, value);

    private static void OnHasErrorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is DependencyObject d)
            d.SetValue(HasErrorProperty, d.GetValue(Validation.HasErrorProperty));
    }
}
```

В разметке у вашего `TextBox` добавляем:

```
<TextBox helpers:TextBoxValidationHelper.HasError="{Binding HasError}">
. . .
</TextBox>
```

При этом, не забудьте описать соответствующее пространство имён:

```
<UserControl x:Class="..." xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:...">
```

Ну и последнее, описываем соответствующее свойство в VM:

```
private bool hasError = false;
public bool HasError
{
    get => this.hasError;
    set => SetProperty(ref this.hasError, value);
}
```

Для справки, `SetProperty`- часть реализации `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (!Equals(storage, value))
    {
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо большое. Вот картинка того что получилось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При ошибке в любом из полей ввода выставляется флаг наличия ошибки.